# Popup showing incrementing number of times xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have noticed one thing with web services in xamarin forms. This is my .cs code

```
static readonly EndpointAddress Endpoint = new EndpointAddress("myWebService");
IVSConnectAPIClient client;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttpBinding();
    client = new IVSConnectAPIClient(binding, Endpoint);
}
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(condition){
        client.UserLoginAsync(pass parameters);
        client.UserLoginCompleted += Client_UserLoginCompleted;
    }
    else{ 
        DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Please enter User ID and Password to proceed.", "OK");
    }
}
public void Client_UserLoginCompleted(object sender, UserLoginCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //result from web service
    if(conditon){
        //go to another page
    }else{
        DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Credential doesnt match the system", "OK");
}
```

so this is what happens. When i enter wrong login id and password and click on the button it perfectly shows me the alert(1 time) but when i click with same incorrect login id and pass 2 the code executes twice and shows the popup 2 times, and when i click with same incorrect login id and pass for the third time popup is showed 3 times, and so on.

Does anyone knows why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each button click, you're subscribing to the `UserLoginCompleted` event again. So each time the event is fired, each subscription is notified.

The solution is to subscribe only once, for example in your constructor:

```
client = new IVSConnectAPIClient(binding, Endpoint);
client.UserLoginCompleted += Client_UserLoginCompleted;
```